# C++ Getting an error with a UDP socket sendto operation when sending a struct

Tags: c++, sockets, struct, udp, udpclient

I've been messing around with [this code](http://www.binarytides.com/udp-socket-programming-in-winsock/) trying to send other things besides a character array.  I created a struct Packet, but I'm getting an "argument of type 'Packet *' is incompatible with parameter of type 'const char*'" error.

It happens when I try to pass my struct Packet into the sendto method.  I included all of the Client Code so you can better see what is going on.  The line with the error is the only thing with a comment over it to make it easier to find.  It's in the while loop, which I probably don't need anymore now that I think about it, but this is just practice code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

#define SERVER "127.0.0.1"  //ip address of udp server
#define BUFLEN 512  //Max length of buffer
#define PORT 8888   //The port on which to listen for incoming data

using namespace std;

struct Packet
{
    int id;
    int number;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in si_other;
    int s, slen=sizeof(si_other);
    char buf[BUFLEN];
    WSADATA wsa;

    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Initialised.\n");

    if ( (s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("socket() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset((char *) &si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
    si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_other.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    si_other.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(SERVER);

    while(1)
    {    
        system("pause");

        struct Packet *thing = new Packet();

        thing->id= htonl(1000);
        thing->number= htonl(7788);

        //*************************************
        //The error is with thing in the sendto statement.
        if (sendto(s, thing, sizeof(*thing) , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("sendto() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        memset(buf,'\0', BUFLEN);
        if (recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("recvfrom() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        puts(buf);
    }

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: typecast thing to (char *)

Comment: @sanjayk79, It was so simple, I thought it couldn't work, but I was wrong!  thanks.